# Python calculate aggregate occurrences between number

Tags: python

I have a problem with counting zeros between ones in the last column, I have to calculate how many possibilities are there, and the number of occurrences for each one.

```
user_guid   episode_number     diff         is_higher_than_1
    1  A             1.0        0                 0 
    2  A             2.0        0.383611          0
    3  A             3.0        0.378889          0
    4  A             4.0        32.364444         1
    5  A             5.0        0.360833          0
    6  A             6.0        0.370278          0
    7  A             7.0        112.430000        1
    8  A             8.0        0.376667          0
    9  A             9.0        0.361389          0
    10 A             10.0       0.372500          0
    11 A             11.0       0.370000          0
    12 A             12.0       58.375833         1
    13 A             13.0       0.375556          0
    14 A             14.0       0.370833          0
    15 A             15.0       0.375000          0
    16 A             16.0       0.374167          0
    17 A             17.0       0.375278          0
    18 A             18.0       0.371944          0
    19 A             19.0       51.503056         1
    20 A             20.0       0.374167          0
    21 A             21.0       0.375000          0
    22 A             22.0       0.375000          0
    23 A             23.0       67.82722          1
```

it should give:

1 occurrence: 0.

2 occurrences in a row: 1.

3 occurrences in a row: 2.

4 occurrences in a row: 1.

5 occurences: 0.

6 occurrences: 1.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Is this with pandas? Please post an example dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done in the complexity *O(N)*. I solved by making `occurences` list, and iterating `rows` once.

code

```py
rows = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
occurences = [0] * len(rows + 1)

__counter = 0
for row in rows:
    if row == 1:
        occurences[__counter] += 1
        __counter = 0
    else:
        __counter += 1
else:
    if row == 0:  # when last element is 0
        occurences[__counter] += 1

print(occurences)
for ix, occ in enumerate(occurences):
    print('{} occurences: {}'.format(ix, occ))
```

output

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 occurences: 0
1 occurences: 0
2 occurences: 1
3 occurences: 2
4 occurences: 1
5 occurences: 0
6 occurences: 1
7 occurences: 0
8 occurences: 0
9 occurences: 0
10 occurences: 0
11 occurences: 0
12 occurences: 0
13 occurences: 0
14 occurences: 0
15 occurences: 0
16 occurences: 0
17 occurences: 0
18 occurences: 0
19 occurences: 0
20 occurences: 0
21 occurences: 0
22 occurences: 0
23 occurences: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use standard library functions, you could use `itertools.groupby()` to do this quickly:

```
max_cnt = 6
cnt = dict()
for i in range(max_cnt):
    cnt[i+1] = 0
for k, g in itertools.groupby(tab1, lambda x: x[4]):
    if k == '1':
        continue
    run_len = len(list(g))
    # print(k, run_len)
    cnt[run_len] += 1
# print(cnt)
for i in range(max_cnt):
    print(i+1, 'occurences in a row:', cnt[i+1])
```

Output

```
1 occurences in a row: 0
2 occurences in a row: 1
3 occurences in a row: 2
4 occurences in a row: 1
5 occurences in a row: 0
6 occurences in a row: 1
```